# How can be this if statement error removed?

Tags: python-3.x

```py
name= input("Enter user name: ")
marks=float(input("Enter user's marks: "))
if marks>=75 : 
    grade="Distinction" 
elif 60<=marks<=75 : 
    grade= "First Division" 
elif 45<=marks<60: 
    grade="Pass" 
else: 
    grade="Fail" 
print("{} you have got {}!".format(name,grade))
```

Error:

```
if marks>=75 : 
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am not able to post this code in code segment, Please review the snapshot and suggest.

Comment: Put your code instead of the image

Comment: name= input("Enter user name: ")
marks=float(input("Enter user's marks: ")
if marks>=75 :
  grade="Distinction"
elif  60<=marks<=75 :
  grade= "First  Division"
elif 45<=marks<60:
  grade="Pass"
else:
  grade="Fail"

print("{} you have got {}!".format(name,grade))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because of the previous line.

You need to add a `)` to the previous line.

```py
marks = float(input("Enter user's mark"))
```